# Can i prevent Spring Boot from catching Mysql exceptions and instead throw my own exceptions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi i'm doing a spring boot server and i realised that in order to register a user, i was checking if it existed first. This means more sql queries and more money for microsoft azure.

I've been trying with some options online, mainly implementing `SQLExceptionTranslator` or extending it's subclasses and i tried to inject it into jdbc template object by making a CommandLineRunner and seting it there. The thing is: it just doesn't work. I ve put a whole load of prints in my implementation and nothing prints. It's just not using it and keeps defaulting the `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` to the spring managed `DataIntegrityViolationException`.
Is there anyway to let me make the mapping instead of allowing spring to map and then catching and resolving it on the `@Service`?

EDIT: If any of you knows who do i inject my implementation to the jdbc template, that would work perfectly too. I've tried autowiring and setting in the `CommandLineRunner`, i dont know any other way to set it, and this one failed miserably

EDIT 2 My very basic implementation (basic just testing if it would work)

```
public class SqlExceptionResolver implements SQLExceptionTranslator {

    @Override
    public DataAccessException translate(String task, String sql, SQLException sqlEx) {
        
        return new Conflict409Exception(task, sqlEx);
    }

}
```

Then to add to the template

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate t;
    

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    t.setExceptionTranslator(new SqlExceptionResolver());
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your SQLExceptionTranslator...at least its signature and the annotations you've put on it?  (or the XML for it if you're going that way).  Also, can you show us how you're "setting it" in the CommandLineRunner?  It's strange that that's where you're doing this.  A more appropriate place would be in a listener that you attach to your application's context, or something like that.  It could work, however.

Comment: Ok...so now how do you get Spring to use that class?  There is no indication that it's something Spring should know about.  It isn't a Bean unless you've got some XML that references that class.

Comment: I editted the post, its very simple im aware, but i test if it works, then build it up

Comment: The word Template worries me.  I'm wondering if your JDBC connections have already been established using the JdbcTemplate you're modifying, and modifying the template this late in the game therefore has no effect.  I don't know JDBC that well.  I just know that Template means other things are created from or by that object, and if that's already happened, changing the Template won't cause any change in behavior.  Just a guess.

Comment: I also tried to define it as a bean, but then the internet told me to set it in the jdbc. Should i put it as a bean as well?

Comment: Its a command line runner, it only executes after stuff is configured so supposedly, yes they are

Comment: I agree with you, the thing is if not here, where do i inject it? i have no clue i tried about everything

Comment: No, it shouldn't need to be a Bean unless you want Spring to manipulate the object in some way, or you want Spring to autowire it somewhere.  Since you're attaching it explicitly, i don't think it needs to be a Bean.

Comment: Agreed. Hence my original question, How do i tell spring to use it? It never does no matter what i did

Comment: yeah.  I get your pain here - I have no quick answer for you, unfortunately :(

Comment: I have an answer, ill have to try/catch the spring then go down the stack trace and get root cause, then throwing my exception. The thing is well this is just a bad solution

Comment: I thought to mention that, but I figured you were looking for more of a "plug it and forget it" solution.  That IS how this is often done.

Comment: I mean it seems unelegant and quite more resource hungry to create exceptions to chatch underlying exceptions, thats why i was trying to work arround it

Comment: Ah...you think you're avoiding the throw?  I get it.  Yeah, that could be, although I wouldn't worry about that.  "Early optimization is the root of all evil." :). The original exception object is created in either case.

Comment: Yes im just gave up and im doing an exception mapper in my service to resolve them